# Rest API for Google Cloud Api Key Credentials

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is there a programmatic way for creating, restricting or deleting for Google Cloud Api Management Credentials, especially API KEYs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the extent of my knowledge there is absolutely no way of making any changes to api keys through code.